# Rearrange position of child divs once for every parent using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 5 identical divs with identical children that are text div and image div. I want to switch the position of the child divs and text divs to come after the image divs. **In other words I want in all articles the image to come above the text.**

All that I tried either takes all text divs and place them after the first image div or place every 5 text divs after every image.

The missing part for me e is how the script run only once for every parent.

*P.S. In the real case div images contain real images but here I use emojis just for example.*

```
<div class="row article1">
    <div class="text-part">text1</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text2</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text3</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text4</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text5</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: Do you want to place all of your `text-part` after their respective next `image-part` element?

Comment: I have read this couple of times and i have no idea what should go where.   `I want to switch the position and the text to before the image in all parents.` ... `text-part` is before  `image-part` already...

Comment: I want to switch the position of the child divs and text divs to come after the image divs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand everything but you can start with this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.article').forEach(e=>{
  let text = e.querySelector('.text-part');
  e.removeChild(text);
  e.appendChild(text);
})
```

```html
<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text1</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text2</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text3</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text4</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>

<div class="row article">
    <div class="text-part">text5</div>
    <div class="image-part"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I want text divs to came after the image divs. Just to switch the position of the childs. In other words I want in all articles the image to come above the text.

Comment: Thank you @PetyoDImitrov please Run code snippet above. I think it's what do you want.